# CouchDB - Get one document lesser than and greater than given key in single request

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I have CouchDB database containing documents with key as timestamp and some value associated with it. Example

```
[
    {"_id": "2018/03/11 10:23:00 +000", "value": "..."},
    {"_id": "2018/03/11 14:25:02 +000", "value": "..."},
    {"_id": "2018/03/12 09:29:12 +000", "value": "..."},
    ...
]
```

Given a timestamp I need to get one document which is lesser than or equal to the given timestamp and one doc which is greater than the given timestsamp.

For example, given TS: "2018/03/11 23:00:00 +000" i it should return

```
[
    {"_id": "2018/03/11 14:25:02 +000", "value": "..."},
    {"_id": "2018/03/12 09:29:12 +000", "value": "..."},
]
```

The way I know it is to do two different requests to get the greater one and lesser one independently. Is there a way to do this in one request?